# React Native Import

Tags: react-native, react-component

Can we use single keyword instead of  '' import { Text, TextInput, Button, StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native'; " in react native? Is there any options available Single keyword for "Text, TextInput, Button, StyleSheet, View"?

```
import { Button, StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native';

export default class ButtonBasics extends Component {
  _onPressButton() {
    alert('You tapped the button!')
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>

        <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
          <Button
            onPress={this._onPressButton}
            title="Press Me"
            color="#841584"
          />
        </View>
        <View style={styles.alternativeLayoutButtonContainer}>
          <Button
            onPress={this._onPressButton}
            title="This looks great!"
          />

        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
   flex: 1,
   justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  buttonContainer: {
    margin: 20
  },
  alternativeLayoutButtonContainer: {
    margin: 20,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-between'
  }
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could `import ReactNative from 'react-native'` and use them as `<ReactNative.View/>` and so on, but I wouldn't recommend that. It's not how 99% of RN devs would expect it to read.

Comment: Answer was very helpul.

Comment: import { Button, StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native'; 
destructuring is the standard common practice in Reactjs and React Native and you should stick to it. But yes you can use dot notation but not advisable.